# How to make a non repeated alarm in android?

Tags: android

I want to make an alarm  to be triggered  at specific time  and this alarm will be only once " non repeated" , I have used the following alarm manager method ,but it repeats daily !! how can i prevent the alarm  from repeating ?? please help me ..

```
final PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.ctx, 0, intent,        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
final AlarmManager am = getAlarmManager();
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,getTriggerTime(), sender);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are your sure, it's repeating? there's a different method to do that (am.setRepeating()), otherwise your code wouldn't repeat. Unless, you set it again, whenever the alarm goes off.

Comment: thanks for fast response , yes its repeating , i have tested it on  my device .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't be repeating since you are using the [AlarmManager.set](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set%28int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) method. Are you sure you are not scheduling it every time you open the app? If the code snippet you are showing is running every time you open the app or running periodically in a background service, then it will schedule an alarm every time it executes.

If this is the case, then you should check some sort of flag that indicates whether the alarm is already scheduled once and prevent this code from running again if it is.

Comment: thanks for helping me , what these flags ? how can i do that ? please can you help me more

Comment: you could store a boolean value in SharedPreferences. Let's call it "isAlarmSet". Just before you run the code above, you check this boolean and only run it if it's false.The first time your code is run, it'll be initialized to false. At the end of your code, you set set it to true. The next time you check it, it'll be true and hence your code will only run once.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
                                AndroidAlarmSMS.this, 0, myIntent, 0);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();



alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                                    calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```